# Uploading file to Amazon S3 bucket : upload works fine but some large files are empty

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

```
    public void upload(List<CommonsMultipartFile> fileUpload) {
        for(CommonsMultipartFile file : fileUpload)
            {
                try
                {
                    String contentType = file.getContentType();
                    String newName = generateFileKey(file);
                    AmazonS3UploadRequest uploadRequest = new AmazonS3UploadRequest.Builder()
                            .bucket(bucket)
                            .contentType(contentType)
                            .newResourceName(newName)
                            .resourceStream(file.getInputStream(), Long.valueOf(file.getBytes().length))
                            .build();
                    uploadToS3(uploadRequest);
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LOG.error("Error while uploading files to s3: ", e);
                    throw new ServiceRuntimeException("Error writing file to s3 bucket");
                }
            }
    }

   public String uploadToS3(AmazonS3UploadRequest uploadRequest) { 

        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(uploadRequest.getResourceLength());
        objectMetadata.setContentType(uploadRequest.getContentType());
        Upload upload = transferManager.upload(uploadRequest.getBucket(), uploadRequest.getNewResourceName(), uploadRequest.getResourceStream(), objectMetadata);
    }
```

I am uploading pdf file to amazon S3 bucket, all files are uploaded successfully 
but large files(15 pages pdf etc) are empty.
Amazon transferManager - is being injected through spring. Amazon credentials are injected from .property file in TansferManager.
Note : .png/.jpeg files are also being uploaded as empty.
Hmm I am kind of confused...what's happening. need some inputs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) *class* from **Apache Commons** thru Streaming API. The code snippet on that page will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to upload your PDF to amazon s3, I assume that you have AWS S3 app Id and secret key.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(appId, appSecret);
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

String bucketPath = "YOUR_S3_BUCKET";

public void upload(List < CommonsMultipartFile > fileUpload) {
    for (CommonsMultipartFile file: fileUpload) {
        try {
            String contentType = file.getContentType();
            String pdfName = generateFileKey(file);
            InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
            meta.setContentLength(is.available());
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketPath, pdfName, is, meta).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while uploading files to s3: ", e);
            throw new ServiceRuntimeException("Error writing file to s3 bucket");
        }
    }
}
```